# Laravel: Passing variable to view and accessing it as a global variable in a function

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to pass a variable to a view so that I can have it as a global variable in a function, but it's not working. I'm not getting any output from the function, but I'm also not getting an error message. Where am I going wrong?

**web.php**

```
<?php
  Route::get('/', function() {
    $abc = 'abc';
    return view('front')->with(['abc'=>$abc]);
  });
?>
```

**front.blade.php**

```
<?php
  function fn() {
    global $abc;
    return $abc;
  }
?>

{{ fn() }}
```

Comment: why you use function in your view? `function fn()`

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: What do you mean by doing this? What do you want to do?

Comment: This is just an example. I just want to be able to access the passed in variable.

Comment: I think this is in vain. Because the mvc architecture is created so that you do not bring the functions to the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can just straight up use your variable, without declaring it `global`:

```
@php
  function fn() {
    return $abc;
  }
@endphp

{{ fn() }}
```

Comment: When I try that it tells me `Undefined variable: abc`

Comment: Are you sure your view actually contains the variable `$abc`? `{{ $abc }}` works as expected?

Comment: Your answer doesn't work, do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe use `function() use ($abc) { return $abc; }`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the dd helper:

```
@php
  function fn() {
    dd(get_defined_vars());
  }
@endphp

{{ fn() }}
```

Read more: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-dd

You can further cutdown on the "useless" variables by doing:

```
@php
  function fn() {
    dd(get_defined_vars()['__data']);
  }
@endphp

{{ fn() }}
```

Comment: Can you explain a little better? How can I use this dd helper?

Comment: you have check with dd helper that which variables are available in your defined function.

Comment: dd(), dump and die.

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything though

Comment: you have to call fn() function. {{ fn() }}

Comment: I still don't see how I can use it

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found that I can do it is to pass the variable into the function as an argument.

```
<?php
  function fn($abc) {
    return $abc;
  }
?>

{{ fn($abc) }}
```